# Struggling with a regex (perl) which parses a file and returns strings of 8 to 24 characters and have no repeated pattern

Tags: regex, repeat

I'm struggling to find a regex which parses a file and returns strings of 8 to 24 characters which have:

1. No given character can be repeated back-to-back 3 times or more (like `"^^^guga"` or &&&&&&&&&^ggjgg or <<<<<<))))&&&&) **and**
2. There are no 2 consecutive repeated patterns in a given string (like `"123123"`or abcabcabcdfg, or 3######u3######u3######u)

Note: A string cannot have have empty/blank space and can be made up of any character you can type on a standard keyboard. (example `0-9a-zA-Z~!@#$%^&*()_+=-\|][{}:;"'?/.>,<` `) I think I got all of them ;)

**Sample Text**

```
=>d`m\cc!=>d`m\cc!=>d`m`\cc!=>d`m\cc0!=>d #abcA167fegh AB&@CDAB&@CDAB&@CD 
I*dKoc,I*dKoc,I*dKoc,I*dKoc,I*dKoc, instance463instance464 Wc^^^7HjkKlp 
)FC7h#!xB;{w97SKm 12345678901234567890
```

**Output** (only 3 strings are valid)

```
#abcA167fegh 
instance463instance464 
)FC7h#!xB;{w97SKm
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with regular expressions...

Comment: Ah...do you mean "immediately repeating", as in "ABAB" is a repeating pattern whereas "ABCAB" is not?

Comment: Note that you're simply requiring strings of unique characters. If any character occurs more than once, then a pattern of length 1 has repeated. If this isn't what you have in mind, you have to specify your problem more precisely, such as "there are no repeating digraphs, trigraphs or longer sequences".

Comment: @TimPietzcker In "ABAB" the one-character pattern "A" repeats twice as just noted in my prior comment.

Comment: How is `instance463instance464` valid, when it contains a repetition of `instance`? Perhaps you mean "no consecutive repetition".  Work on specifying problems better, and the programming may just pop out of it as a byproduct. :)

Comment: @SteveP Oh, you can probably do it with something that is **called** regular expressions in Perl.

Comment: I reworded your question in the hope of clarifying it. If I changed the meaning of your question, please correct the edit.

Comment: Part1 - Thanks for chiming in guys! Yes, my problem above needs clarification: 3 characters repeating 'back-to-back' 2 pattern or more "immediately repeating", as mentioned by Tim above, is the keyword! iow, the word "impressive" is OK b/c the 's' only repeats twice in the string, but "impressiveimpressive", is NOT OK, same thing for ABAB, it too should be discarded not because A appears twice in the string, but because AB repeats immediately...

Comment: Part2 - So strings like this should be discarded: a^5hAAAgffA% not b/c 'A' appears 4 times in the string, but b/c 'A' followed another 'A', and yet another one, which makes makes 3 back-to-back chars. Same thing here: "AB&@CDAB&@CDAB&@CD" 'AB&@CD' keeps repeating, so it should discarded. As for "instance463instance464" it is valid b/c no character or pattern in the string repeats back-to-back 3 times and two times respectively. If it were instance463instance463, instead, then it would be invalid...Hope this helps...P.S. I've made a few edits to the problem description above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on your example:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?:(?!(\S{2,})\1)(?!(\S)\2\2)\S){8,24}(?=$|\s)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=^|\s)        # Assert we're at the start of a "word" 
(?:              # Start a non-capturing group:
 (?!(\S{2,})\1)  # Assert that no repeated sequence of characters starts here
 (?!(\S)\2\2)    # Assert that no runs of three identical characters starts here
 \S              # Match a non-whitespace character
){8,24}          # Repeat 8-24 times
(?=$|\s)         # Assert we're at the end of a "word"
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/zZ3gH6).

Comment: @SteveP.: Did I test recursive patterns? No, why? I did test my regex (did you see the link?).

Comment: Scratch that, meant back-references... Didn't realize that you changed the question.  I don't think that is what he wanted, which is why I was confused about this working...

Comment: @SteveP.: Yes, I did test it outside of regex101, too. (But regex101 is excellent. I haven't found bugs in it for quite a while now).

Comment: @SteveP.: I only changed the formatting and defined "repeated pattern" to make it explicit and conforming to the OP's own sample input/output, so I'm quite confident that that's what he wanted. Of course, I may be wrong, so let's see if there is any reaction...

Comment: It's possible, but I'm not sure where you got the back-to-back 3 times or more from.  Perhaps I misinterpreted what he stated.

Comment: @SteveP.: That was in his original question; I didn't change that part at all (except for providing an example).

Comment: @Tim, Thank You Very Much! It's working, but when I switch to Python or Java on regex101.com it doesn't work!! Any idea why? Thanks Again!